# Load properties from a yaml file in Junit test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, properties, yaml

I'm writing a junit test and I'm not able to get the value from a propertie file using @Value.

Here is my code

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBootConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")

    public class AppTest {

        @Value("${app.url}")
        private String url;

        @Test
        public void test() 
            Assert.assertEquals(url, "xxxxx");
        }
    }
```

and my application-test.yml file is as follow:

```
app:
   url:xxxx
```

How may I get the value from the yaml file using the spring annotation @Value ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing `@PropertySource` annotation to import your file.
Example : `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`

**Update**

Try adding the following: `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class, 
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)`

Comment: but yhis works if I use a .properties file, I am using a yml file